# How to Improve if algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

How do this better? Without repeating code someFunction(1).

```
        if(someTrueOrFalse)
        {
                if(OthersomeTrueOrFalse)
                {
                    someFunction(1);
                }
        } 
        else
        {
            someFunction(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `A` = someTrueOrFalse and `B` = OthersomeTrueOrFalse

```
 A | B | outcome
-----------------
 0 | 0 |    1
 0 | 1 |    1
 1 | 0 |    0
 1 | 1 |    1
```

Hence:

```
if (!(someTrueOrFalse && !OthersomeTrueOrFalse)) {
    someFunction(1);
}
```

or, equivalently, as commented by @axiac

```
if (!someTrueOrFalse || OthersomeTrueOrFalse) {
    someFunction(1);
}
```

It depends on the situation which of the two looks better, I guess (or sometimes it's just a matter of taste).

Comment: This is the same as `if (! someTrueOrFalse || OthersomeTrueOrFalse)` that is easier to understand.

Comment: @axiac answer's approach looks to me easier to understand: Theres only 1 situation function must not run: The 3rd one. So every case apart from 3rd, run it. Your is like these 3 cases are true, (1,2 and 4) and then you describe them.

Comment: @axiac thanks, added that to the answer, although my intention for this answer was just to show how this is done with a truth table.